# How to avoid while loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, while-loop, query-optimization

I have one query and because of this query execution time is increasing and taking time to execute in SQL Server 2016.

```
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #SlabWeight);    

WHILE ( @ID <= @Count )    
BEGIN    
    SELECT  @Weight = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), weight)    
    FROM    #SlabWeight    
    WHERE   ID = @ID;    

    SET @WeightList += '[' + @Weight + '],';    
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ALTER TABLE #TempData ADD ['    
        + @Weight + '] DECIMAL(18,2), [' + @Weight    
        + '_BasedOn] VARCHAR(10)';    
    SET @SelectStatment = @SelectStatment + ' , [' + @Weight + '] , [' + @Weight + '_BasedOn]';    
    SET @ID += 1;    
END;
```

Can anyone tell me how to avoid using a while loop in this query?

Comment: @Zhorov it's 2016.

Comment: You need to change your design... a design that requires regularly, dynamically, adding new columns is broken.

Comment: @DaleK can you please suggest ?

Comment: Um no - I have no idea what you system is attempting to do or why. All I know is that instead of adding new columns you should probably be adding rows somewhere - thats how one leverages a database.

Comment: Although I agree that Dale K probably is right about your approach being .. unlikely to be what it should be, I also don't think the loop itself is slow; it's probably the recurring `ALTER TABLE ADD <column>` that's killing you. Rather than building a new one for each loop, why not simply keep adding all the required columns to 1 single `ALTER TABLE ..` statement so the execute only needs to rebuild the table once.
Also, I'd probably would use a cursor rather than this 'counter' construction.